# How can I set a certain key on my keyboard to change the Windows 7 keyboard input language?

Tags: windows-7, keyboard, input

I often write in two different languages (English/German), and it's too much trouble for me to use a mouse to click on the taskbar to change from one keybard input language to another. I would like to be able to do so at the press of a button. Is there a way in Windows 7 to toggle between keyboard input languages like this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Right click the Language Bar and click Settings.
In the Text Services and Input Languages window, click the Advanced Key Settings tab.
You can now choose key sequences for any of the listed actions.
The first action, "Between input languages", is what you are looking for.
[image: Text Services and Input Languages]